# Recyclerview onBindViewHolder repeat many times

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, repeat

public class TripsMyEventAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
static List<TripData> tripData;

static Context c;

static LocationConverter locationConverter

public TripsMyEventAdapter(List<TripData> tripData, Context c){
    this.tripData = tripData;
    this.c=c;
    locationConverter = new LocationConverter(c);
}

@Override
public TripsMyEventAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    ViewHolder vh;
    View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyler_bookmark_trips,viewGroup,false);
    // create ViewHolder
    vh = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    viewHolder.itemView.setTag(tripData.get(position));
    if(tripData.get(position).getImageUrl().contains("https"))
        Picasso.with(c).load(tripData.get(position).getImageUrl()).into(viewHolder.image);
    else {
        Log.d("onBindViewHolder",position+"");
        viewHolder.image.setImageBitmap(null);
        new LoadImage(viewHolder, position).execute();
    }
    //loadImage(tripData.get(position).getImageUrl(),viewHolder.image);
    viewHolder.title.setText(tripData.get(position).getTitle());
    viewHolder.date.setText(tripData.get(position).getDate());
    viewHolder.creator.setText(tripData.get(position).getCreator());
    viewHolder.description.setText(Html.fromHtml(tripData.get(position).getDescription()).toString().replace("equals","="));
    viewHolder.budget.setText(tripData.get(position).getBudget());
    if(tripData.get(position).getMaxNum().equals("unlimited"))
        viewHolder.partnerNum.setText(tripData.get(position).getMaxNum());
    else
        viewHolder.partnerNum.setText(tripData.get(position).getMinNum()+"~"+ tripData.get(position).getMaxNum());
    viewHolder.eventCreator = tripData.get(position).getCreator();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return tripData.size();
}

// inner class to hold a reference to each item of RecyclerView
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    public TextView title,date,creator,description,budget,partnerNum;
    public RelativeLayout container;
    public CircleImageView image;
    public String eventCreator;
    public String firstname,lastname,userName;

    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);
        itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(this);
        image = (CircleImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        title = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        date = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
        creator = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.tvCreator);
        description = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
        budget = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.tvBudget);
        partnerNum = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.tvNumber);
        container = (RelativeLayout)itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.container);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {


        firstname = LocalDB.getDataBySQL("SELECT firstname FROM User", 0, "firstname");
        lastname = LocalDB.getDataBySQL("SELECT lastname FROM User", 0, "lastname");
        userName = firstname+" "+lastname;
        if(userName.equals(eventCreator)) {
            Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), CreatorTripDetail.class);
            int position = this.getAdapterPosition();
            i.putExtra("tid", tripData.get(position).getTid());
            i.putExtra("uid", tripData.get(position).getUid());
            view.getContext().startActivity(i);
        }else {
            Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(),TripDetail.class);
            int position = this.getAdapterPosition();
            i.putExtra("tid", tripData.get(position).getTid());
            i.putExtra("uid", tripData.get(position).getUid());
            view.getContext().startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}

public class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Void> {     //This class use to load the data from server first time
    //declare other objects as per your need
    Bitmap iconBitmap;
    CircleImageView circleImageView;
    ViewHolder v;
    String url;
    int position;

    public LoadImage(ViewHolder v, int position){
        this.v = v;
        circleImageView = v.image;
        this.position = position;
        url = tripData.get(position).getImageUrl();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {

    };
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Object... params)
    {
        String serverPath = c.getResources().getString(R.string.user)+"getImage";
        ImageHelper i = new ImageHelper(c,serverPath,url);
        Thread t = new Thread(i);
        t.start();
        try {
            t.join();
            iconBitmap = i.getBitmap();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(iconBitmap!=null&&circleImageView.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE&&v.getAdapterPosition()==position) {
            circleImageView.setImageBitmap(iconBitmap);
        }
    };
}
```

}

And the log message

> 03-13 23:38:32.763 14586-14586/org.wings_lab.backpackpairing D/onBindViewHolder: 2
>   03-13 23:38:32.763 14586-14586/org.wings_lab.backpackpairing D/onBindViewHolder: 2
>   03-13 23:38:32.793 14586-14586/org.wings_lab.backpackpairing D/onBindViewHolder: 2
>   03-13 23:38:32.793 14586-14586/org.wings_lab.backpackpairing D/onBindViewHolder: 2
>   03-13 23:38:32.823 14586-14586/org.wings_lab.backpackpairing D/onBindViewHolder: 2
>   03-13 23:38:32.823 14586-14586/org.wings_lab.backpackpairing D/onBindViewHolder: 2
>   03-13 23:38:32.843 14586-14586/org.wings_lab.backpackpairing D/onBindViewHolder: 2
>   03-13 23:38:32.843 14586-14586/org.wings_lab.backpackpairing D/onBindViewHolder: 2
>   03-13 23:38:32.853 14586-14586/org.wings_lab.backpackpairing D/onBindViewHolder: 2
>   03-13 23:38:32.863 14586-14586/org.wings_lab.backpackpairing D/onBindViewHolder: 2
>   03-13 23:38:32.873 14586-14586/org.wings_lab.backpackpairing D/onBindViewHolder: 2
>   03-13 23:38:32.873 14586-14586/org.wings_lab.backpackpairing D/onBindViewHolder: 2
>   03-13 23:38:32.893 14586-14586/org.wings_lab.backpackpairing D/onBindViewHolder: 2
>   03-13 23:38:32.893 14586-14586/org.wings_lab.backpackpairing D/onBindViewHolder: 2
>   03-13 23:38:32.903 14586-14586/org.wings_lab.backpackpairing D/onBindViewHolder: 2
>   03-13 23:38:32.903 14586-14586/org.wings_lab.backpackpairing D/onBindViewHolder: 2
>   03-13 23:38:32.923 14586-14586/org.wings_lab.backpackpairing D/onBindViewHolder: 2
>   03-13 23:38:32.923 14586-14586/org.wings_lab.backpackpairing D/onBindViewHolder: 2
>   03-13 23:38:32.933 14586-14586/org.wings_lab.backpackpairing D/onBindViewHolder: 2
>   03-13 23:38:32.933 14586-14586/org.wings_lab.backpackpairing D/onBindViewHolder: 2
>   03-13 23:38:32.943 14586-14586/org.wings_lab.backpackpairing D/onBindViewHolder: 2
>   03-13 23:38:32.943 14586-14586/org.wings_lab.backpackpairing D/onBindViewHolder: 2
>   03-13 23:38:32.963 14586-14586/org.wings_lab.backpackpairing D/onBindViewHolder: 2
>   03-13 23:38:32.963 14586-14586/org.wings_lab.backpackpairing D/onBindViewHolder: 2
>   03-13 23:38:32.973 14586-14586/org.wings_lab.backpackpairing D/onBindViewHolder: 2
>   03-13 23:38:32.973 14586-14586/org.wings_lab.backpackpairing D/onBindViewHolder: 2
>   03-13 23:38:32.983 14586-14586/org.wings_lab.backpackpairing D/onBindViewHolder: 2
>   03-13 23:38:32.983 14586-14586/org.wings_lab.backpackpairing D/onBindViewHolder: 2
>   03-13 23:38:33.003 14586-14586/org.wings_lab.backpackpairing D/onBindViewHolder: 2
>   03-13 23:38:33.003 14586-14586/org.wings_lab.backpackpairing D/onBindViewHolder: 2
>   03-13 23:38:33.013 14586-14586/org.wings_lab.backpackpairing D/onBindViewHolder: 2
>   03-13 23:38:33.013 14586-14586/org.wings_lab.backpackpairing D/onBindViewHolder: 2

It repeats to load image 30 times...
How to fix this problems?

Comment: What problem does this cause?  Meaning, is there a behavior in the app that is not correct?  If everything's working right I wouldn't worry about how many times a method is called.

Comment: I post to nodejs server get image everytime and it make the server side inefficiency...

Comment: Why? protected Void doInBackground function with big "V"? should be "void"